# Facebook Like taking root domain

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to implement a Facebook Like button on my site. It's at a subdomain.

I've tried putting the link in the script tag of the Like button and now I'm trying to use Open Graph meta tags. Neither works. I have:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Site"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/image1.png"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mysite.example.com/"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="123123123"/>
```

And the button:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like show_faces="false" width="450"></fb:like>
```

It works, but when I like something it says:

> John likes My Site on example.com.

How can I make it use the subdomain? I have the subdomain listed in the application settings as well.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `I have the subdomain listed in the application settings as well` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the full url of the page to like as the href value on the fb:like element. Something like:

```
<fb:like href="http://mysite.example.com/" show_faces="false" width="450"></fb:like>
```